# Scrape google visualization table from a webpage into R

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-visualization, tidyverse, rvest

Trying to scarpe a Market Valuation table from this webpage:
https://www.starcapital.de/en/research/stock-market-valuation/
The website is dynamic and asks for user location. The table of interest is listed as class "google-visualization-table-table".

I have tried the following r code

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.starcapital.de/en/research/stock-market-valuation/"
valuation <- url %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@id="infotable_div2"]/div/div/table') %>%
  html_table()
valuation <- valuation[[1]]
```

and I get no error but no results. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem you will run into pretty often when scraping websites. The problem here is that this webpage is dynamic. That is, it uses JavaScript to create the visualization and this is done after the page loads. And, crucially here, after `rvest` downloads the page which is why you don't see it with your code. I confirmed this by disabling JavaScript in Chrome and I see that the chart is missing from the page.

That said, you aren't out of luck! I again used Chrome's Developer Tools' Network pane to look through the requests the page was making. Pages like this that create charts dynamically often make a separate network request to grab data before creating the chart. After some scrolling and poking around, I saw one that looks like the dataset you're interested in:

https://www.starcapital.de/fileadmin/charts/Res_Aktienmarktbewertungen_FundamentalKZ_Tbl.php?lang=en

Open that up in your browser and take a look. Let me know if that's the data you were hoping to get. It's in a somewhat custom-looking JSON format so you may end up needing to write a bit of code to get it into R. Check out the [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) package for manipulating the JSON and the [httr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/) package for getting the data from that URL into R.

Edit: An alternative approach would be to use an R package that can run the dynamic part of the page (that gets the data to make the chart/table) such as [splashr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splashr/). There are a few other R packages out there that can do this but that's one I'm familiar with.